# how to convert pandas dataframe to numpy array of float data type

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a .csv file and I want to convert it to numpy dtype('float64')

my code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas import read_csv

df=read_csv('input.csv')
df=df['data']
df.to_numpy() ---> produces numpy array of object data type and i want it to be dtype('float64')
```

Hope experts may help me.Thanks.

Data sample

```
0        -3.288733e-08, 1.648743e-09, 2.202711e-08, 2.7...
1        2.345769e-07, 2.054583e-07, 1.610073e-07, 1.14...
2        -1.386798e-07, -8.212822e-08, -4.192486e-08, -...
3        -4.234607e-08, 2.526512e-10, 2.222485e-08, 3.3...
4        3.899913e-08, 5.349818e-08, 5.65899e-08, 5.424...
       

                    ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If same number of floats in each row is possible use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with cast to floats and then convert `DataFrame` to numpy array:

```
df=read_csv('input.csv')

arr = df['data'].str.split(', ', expand=True).astype(float).to_numpy()
```

Comment: @pro - what is `print (df['data'].head().tolist())` ?

Comment: @pro - But data seems float type, what is `print (df['data'].dtype)` ?

Comment: its object data type

Comment: @pro - I add test with data, for me solution working well. Real data in column are different?

Comment: @pro - Can you add data sample to question?

Comment: @pro - Can you test now?

Comment: @pro - Super, so same number of floats per row?

Comment: yes @jezrael u r right